# Erro ao atualizar o MySQL.Data

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

Eu fiz a atualização do MySQL.Data e MySQL.Data.Entity da versão 6.9.9 para a versão 6.10.4 e comecei a receber o erro abaixo :

> Regras de segurança de herança foram violadas pelo tipo: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices'. Os tipos derivados devem corresponder à acessibilidade de segurança do tipo de base ou ser menos acessíveis.

Este erro ocorre na hora que vai criar a instância do DbContext

Comment: Estou Desde ontem brigando com essa atualização, não achei um jeito pra realmente corrigir no StackOverflow só gringo falaram que tem q fazer downgrade da versão. Desinstala o MySQL Connector, depois instala a versão 6.9.10 Altera os pacotes do Nuget pra essa versão tbm.